# Question about the simple example for batch normalization given in "deep learning" book

Tags: deep-learning

In the section about batch normalization of Deep Learning book by Ian Goodfellow ([chapter link](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html)) there is the follwing text:

> As  example, suppose we have a deep neural network that has only one
>   unit per layerand does not use an activation function at each hidden
>   layer: $y=x w_1 w_2 w_3 \ldots w_l$. Here, $w_i$ provides the weight used by
>   layer $i$. The output of layer $i$ is  $h_i=h_{i−1} wi$. The output $y$ is a
>   linear function of the input $x$, but a nonlinear function of the weights
>   $w_i$.

Why y is nonlinear with respect to w_i?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well. One unit per layer means one neuron. Then w_i are scalar, not necessarily x and y. Then I don't really understand this statement. I delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the statement meant was when given weights $w_1,...,w_n$ are fixed, output is linear proportional to $x$, but as it mentions

> nonlinear function of the weights w_i

Given a set of weights (more than one being varied), they do not linearly add to produce an output like

$y=w_1x_1+...+w_nx_n$

but rather non-linearly like

$y=w_1w_2..w_n*x$ (each $w_i$ is a dimension in the hyperspace)

And I think it would become more clearer from the statement "*Output is linear to any weight $w_i$ but non-linear to weights $w_i$*".

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the answer. what does the ∗ operator represents I we have one unit per layer, each w_i is a scalar, so how can it be not linear?

Comment: @amit * is just a multiplication operator. In the case which you did not understand, $w_i$ is no scalar but a variable. The statement is saying that if $w_i$'s are variable and lets consider them as axis of nD space, changing some of them would not produce a linear output since they are getting multiplied. But keeping all weights constant except one weight $w_i$, so any changes in that weight produce a linear output, in this case.

Comment: I still fail to understand. 
What do you mean by considering them as axis of nD space?
Each w_i is a scalar variable representing one dimension in some W vector?
How multiplying them make sense in that context?

Comment: Okay, my bad. They are scalars but are variables. Forget the axis too. Simply putting, Is $z =k*x*y$ linear? if k is a constant and x,y are variables? No. Taking this case as an equivalence of the network, $x,y$ are weights of the network with $k$ being the $x$ in the last equation of my answer. So $x,y$ are in a non-linear equation. Are you able to compare this $z=k*x*y$ with $y=x*w_1*w_2..*w_n$ and see what are the variables(weights) and why the equation is non-linear with respect to weights $w_i$. If you are still unclear, we can extend it in chat.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $w_1 = w_2 =... w_n = w$ then $y = w^n \times x $. In this sense is $y$ a linear function of $x$ and a non-linear function of $w$.

Comment: Can you explain how this differs from the accepted answer?

Comment: it does not differ that much. It's just a different perspective.